# Correct formula for the std deviation of the difference between two means in case of unequal variance?

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, random-variable, standard-deviation

@whuber stop closing my question, this is really inappropriate to block me from aksing my question!

I am trying again to post my question, as it is not a duplicate and not answered in any other similiar questions.

I have two random variables which are independent and normally distributed.

In this [document](https://ncss-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/themes/ncss/pdf/Procedures/NCSS/Two-Sample_T-Test_for_Non-Inferiority.pdf) on page 198-9 it says:

[image: s1dfse]

I am wondering about this formula.

In general it [holds](http://www.mathspadilla.com/macsII/Unit10-Sampling/sampling_distribution_of_difference_between_means.html):

[image: s5]

or on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_distribution):

[image: s4]

Therefore if we assume unequal variance, I would think like this:

$s_{\bar{X}_T-\bar{X}_C}=\sqrt{s^2_T/n_1+s^2_C/n_2}$

Where is my mistake here?

In the document later on for the standard error it says:

[image: s]

So their formula for std error corresponds to my formula for the std dev. I don't get the derivation of these $s_{\bar{X}_T-\bar{X}_C}$ vs $SE_{\bar{X}_T-\bar{X}_C}$.